# An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS90023: Invalid STS request

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, authentication, azure-ad, ad

I have an issue with my AD account.

I tried using Python to access SharePoint list folder. But I am facing an issue, as given below.

This is error:

> An error occurred while retrieving token from XML response: AADSTS90023: Invalid STS request.

**Note:**
When I tried login with my friend's AD account, it worked fine. I noted other issue, when I try to connect to SharePoint list with my AD from Microsoft Access (it always shows form login again and again) & I cannot connect.

How can we solve this issue?

Comment: what does “i tried login with my friend AD” mean?  Can you *re-type* your **entire question** into google translate to get it into English?

Comment: For issue #1:  how are you acquiring the Auth Token?  For issue #2:  which version of Access are you using?